# Series and probability Games

Tags: probability

Suppose we have Series 1 and Series 2, and four teams $A,B,C,D$. $A$ and $B$ play in Series 1 and $C$ and $D$ play in Series 2. In each series, the first team to win 3 games wins the series. The home team has a $3/4$ chance of winning in each game. The winner of each series plays each other in a similar format. What is the probability of $A$ defeating $D$ in the final series $3-2$?

The home team is based on:

```
 Game #              Home Team
 Game 1                 A/C
 Game 2                 A/C
 Game 3                 B/D
 Game 4(if necessary)   B/D
 Game 5(if necessary)   A/C
```

Can the probability be decomposed to something like: $$P(\text{A defeats D 3-2}) = P(\text{A defeats D 3-2}|\text{A wins Series 1 and D wins Series 2})$$

**Added**  In the $A/C$ notation, Game 1 of Series 1 is played in A's hometown and Game 1 of Series 2 is played in C's hometown, etc.

Games 1,2, and 5 will be played in the Series 1 winner's hometown, Games 3 and 4 will be played in Series 2 winner hometown.

Comment: Your notation for the Home Team isn't clear.  In, say, the $A/C$ series...is $A$ always the home team?  Does it alternate?  In the final series between the two winners...how does home team advantage sort out?

Comment: To your closing question:  No.  What you want isn't that conditional probability since the answer you want depends (heavily) on the probability that $A$ and $D$ win their respective series.  You have to multiply your conditional by the probability that both $A,D$ win.

Comment: @lulu: Games 1,2, and 5 will be played in the Series 1 winner's hometown, Games 3 and 4 will be played in Series 2 winner hometown.In the $A/C$ notation, Game 1 of Series 1 is played in A's hometown and Game 1 of Series 2 is played in C's hometown, etc..

Comment: Regardless of the confusion:  because of the home team advantage, it's probably easiest to simply write out all the cases.  It's tedious, but not at all difficult.

Comment: @lulu: See my addition.

Comment: Got it.  You could avoid writing out all the cases by breaking it into scenarios where, say, $A$ wins exactly $3$ home games, or $2$, or $1$.  That might be easier than just writing it all out, though I'd probably just go for the brute force method.  If the series were longer , brute force would be unacceptable and my second suggestion would look better.

Comment: On review, I think my second suggestion is probably better.  Just assume that all seven games are played even if a winner is known before the seventh game (that doesn't change the eventual winner).  To be sure, both methods are somewhat ugly computationally but I think the second method is considerably less error prone.

Comment: Sorry, meant "fifth" where I wrote "seventh".  And if you do it that way, which I now think is probably optimal, then it isn't true that $m+n=3$ any more...now you need $m+n≥3$.